# Why move task does not move symlinks?

Tags: deployment, ant, move, symlink

I have a deployment script where I move a directory to another directory. In this directory I have a symlink relative to a parent folder like this:

```
abc -> ../dir/file
```

`dir/file` is also in the directory which gets deployed.

I move the directory with the following lines of xml:

```
<move todir="${deploy.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${to.deploy}">
        <include name="**/*" />
    </fileset>
</move>
```

Everything gets moved but not the symlinks. The stay in the `${deploy.dir}`. Why? Maybe Ant does not know how to set the new symlink (the new location)?

How can you fix this? Delete the symlink and use the `symlink` target to make a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbolic links are special files. Ant is not fully capable of handling them.  [Here is the note](http://ant.apache.org/manual/platform.html).

> Ant is not symbolic link aware in moves, deletes and when recursing
>   down a tree of directories to build up a list of files. Unexpected
>   things can happen.

You need a custom solution , probably using [`readlink`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink).  Question [How do I move a relative symbolic link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523159/how-do-i-move-a-relative-symbolic-link) and answers points to additional solutions (nothing to do with ant, though)

Comment: "unexpected things can happen" does not sound very nice to me for a deployment script. That could also mean, it f*cks up everything and deletes everything? :-) But nevertheless, I found out that I can do it with the symlink target. I don't know why ant can handle symlinks inside the symlink target, but not the move target...

Comment: @tester : java does not support symlinks directly. ant works around by comparing paths (canonical and absolute).  The note says this is error prone on non-unix platforms.